# WebClient throws: "(403) Forbidden" when entering some pages

Tags: c#, webclient

My code:

```
System.Net.WebClient webClient = new System.Net.WebClient();
webClient.Headers.Add( "user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)" );
Stream data = webClient.OpenRead( "http://www.sts.pl" );
```

Works fine on most pages, but throws exception:

```
The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.
```

when trying to open page:

https://www.sts.pl

or

http://www.sts.pl

What is so specyfic on this page?

**I do not have any account on this page and was never login to it using browser.**
Just in the browser it loads fine, but using WebClient throws exception.

Comment: Try adding a slash at the end : https://www.sts.pl/  Somebody last week solved issue with slash at end.

Comment: Adding slash doesn't help

Comment: Look at the browser request and your programs request in Fiddler, and examine what is different between the two.

Comment: I was going to suggest same as Amy.  Check HTTP version for 1.0 or 1.1.  The page may be built with different compatibility version for Mozilla so make sure you check the headers on good page and bad page.